# Best way to convert 2D memory allocation to 1D vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

What is the fastest way to convert a 2D memory allocation to a 1D vector? Right now, I am using nested loops to do it by referring each value at a time. Would it be possible use memcpy or copy to gain speed? I have the following:

```
Ipp32f* datamem = ippiMalloc_32f_C1(size0, size1, &(steps)); 
Ipp32f* datamem2 = ippiMalloc_32f_C1(size0, size1, &(steps)); s

std::vector<double> result(2*size0*size1); 
int count = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < size0; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < size1; k++){
            Ipp32f* pointer = (Ipp32f)((Ipp8u*)datamem + steps * k + sizeof(Ipp32f) * j); 
            result[count] = *pointer; 
            count++; 
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size0; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < size1; k++){
            Ipp32f* pointer = (Ipp32f)((Ipp8u*)datamem2 + step * k + sizeof(Ipp32f) * j); 
            result[count] = *pointer; 
            count++; 
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates a vector where each index are referenced by a number store in datamem and datamem2. Is there a better way to this?

Comment: Where's the definition for `datamem`?  Seems pretty important.

Comment: If the array is a true 2D array, then it already is a 1D array by the mere fact that 2D arrays store the data contiguously, no different than a 1D array.  Which means that you need to post *how* this 2D-array is declared and/or built.

Comment: I added the def to datamem

Comment: What is `ippiMalloc`?  Does it create the data in contiguous memory?

Comment: Yes it is a function from Intel performance library IPP

Comment: You could possibly be able to create a vector using `return std::vector<double> result(memory_start, memory_end+1);` and forget all of those loops.  According to [this](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/ipp/ipp_manual/IPPI/ippi_ch3/functn_Malloc.htm), the memory is allocated as one chunk.  Contiguous memory can always be considered as a 1-dimensional array -- you just need to know how to access the beginning and end of this array.

Comment: oh sounds promising! what would be memory_start and memory_end in this context and what if I have 2 memory allocations?

Comment: IMO, you are just asking for trouble by casting Ipp32f to Ipp8u and back. It makes the code more difficult to understand, especially when there is a out-of-the-box solution already present. Use [IppiCopy(...)](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-2-image-processing/image-data-exchange-and-initialization-functions/copy-1.html). *Hint: HxW in 2D is (H*W)x1 in 1D*